# How does numpy generate random number based on certain distributions (normal, poisson, exponential...)

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy has functions such as numpy.random.poisson generates a random number that follows the Poisson distribution. But, which sampling method does it use? I know that you can use Inverse Sampling method to generate numbers that follow a distribution, but which does Numpy employ?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.poisson.html#numpy.random.Generator.poisson

Comment: @Guy The documentation does not mention the specific technique used to generate numbers followed by a Poisson distribution

Comment: Some information can be found in the numpy documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html)

Comment: Have you looked the docs of the individual distributions?  I looked at a couple of the Wiki references, which 'computational methods' sections.